How can delet a bad-tag from Tags list or inform the moderators?
I find two questions using shors tag, when there is a tag (shors-algorithm), that I created some days ago, that is more precise and has the wiki.
What is the procedure for a case like this, that there is a "bad tag" and should be deleted, or should inform the moderators to investigate it?
I asked this question because I could not find a button or something like that to raise a flag.


What is the procedure for a case like this, that there is a "bad tag" and should be deleted, or should inform the moderators to investigate it?

It depends. Asking on Meta about it as you did is always a good fallback though. For the kind of scenario in question here where there's a clearly superior tag, the action to be taken mostly depends on the amount of questions tagged with the inferior one and the name of the inferior one.

If the name of the inferior one is catchy and distinct enough that it's easier to find for some people, notify the moderators (via a meta post) and ask for the inferior tag to be merged into the superior tag.
If there is only a small number of questions with the inferior tag, e.g. less than 5, just edit the tags. Once the tag is no longer used, the system will automatically delete it (after a while).
If there is a medium-large amount of questions with the inferior tag, e.g. less than 20, do the re-tagging in batches of 5 a day as to not clogg up the recently active questions page too much.
If there's a large amount of questions, make a Meta post and ask for the moderators to merge the tags potentially create a tag synoym. A mod initiated merge operation will not bump the re-tagged questions to the recently active page.

Note that, if you think there's even a slight chance of others disagreeing with the re-tagging, ask on Meta in any case before doing anything.
As for the concrete case at hand, the name shors-algorithm is very much clearer, used more and more recently used while the shors only has its shortness going for it. It's quite uncontroversial to merge these two, so I just went ahead and did that.

Thank you for answering my question, it helps me and I appreciate you for the efforts.
